# Pull money out of old pension and start a stock trading account?

Tags: united-states, stocks, 401k, pension, withdrawal

I have 10k in an old pension plan with a company I no longer work for. I have a 401k currently with my present employer and would like to take the 5k and start an stock trading account. Would this be wise?

Comment: You may feel that is not an exact duplicate - but just consider if your 'stock trading account' would (a) beat out the funds available in your pension [statistically, this isn't often done], and (b) it would **further** beat out the penalties of early withdrawal.

Comment: Is the pension plan a "pension" or is it a 401(k)? Can you cash in the pension fund?

Comment: When you say "stock trading account" are you referring to an IRA or a brokerage account? What are your goals and other assets?

Comment: It is a pension fund and I can start dispersing it or take a lump sum since I have became 56 yrs. I would like to fund a brokerage account. It is thru Hertz which i used to work for about 10 years ago. I have edited the question to show that it actually is 10k in there.

Comment: Note that you may be eligible to _roll over_ the money in the pension fund into a self-directed Individual IRA and do all the stock trading you like with that, without paying tax on a withdrawal.